# Remove the blue outline of HTML elements

Tags: html, css

I have created a dotted nav, and I noticed that when I click any **li** on iPad, two blue outline boxes would show; when clicking on laptop, they don't show.

I don't think this is the **focus** state because I tried doing **a:focus: { outline: none }**, they were still appearing. Is there anyway to remove these two ugly boxes? If so, would that decrease the **accessibility**? Another sort of off-topic question is that, as I was **tabbing** through my website, the **nav** was completely **skipped**, any idea why? Thank you!

Blue boxes don't show on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28jecnha/5/) though. So IDK if this would be helpful... But if you notice any bad practice, please do point it out, thanks!

[image: screenshot]

**HTML**

```
<nav class="nav"> 
    <ul class="nav-items"> 
        <li>
            <a href="#intro">
                <span class="dot"></span>
            </a>
            <span class="dot-label">Intro</span>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#about">
                <span class="dot"></span>
            </a>
            <span class="dot-label">About</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS (partial)**

```
.nav {
  position: fixed;
}

.nav-items a {
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 30px;
  order: 2;
}

.dot {
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  transition: transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 150;
}

.dot-label {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  order: 1;
  user-select: none;
}

.nav-items a:hover .dot {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.nav-items a:hover + span.dot-label {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's interpreting the bullets as text, like unicode characters, and touch-clicking the area is selecting it. Have you tried `nav li {user-select: none;}`?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that, still the same.